# Facebook authentication with Express using a custom login page

Tags: node.js, express, facebook-login, passport-facebook

Currently I am trying to create a login page that would allow a user to authenticate through his facebook account. All the tutorials I found explain how to implement it, but in all implementations their websites take a user to Facebook's login window. I wonder if it is possible to use my own login page to provide a username and password using my own form and then authenticate the user on the server side without any Facebook pages popping up?

Thank you in advance

Comment: This is not possible. Facebook don't want to allow external websites to be able to capture users login information.

Comment: Thank you, @SlashmanX, for your answer. you saved me from a lot of hours of research